# Open source libraries for abstracting database access in C++?

Tags: c++, database

I'm looking for options for abstracting database server details away from my application (in c++), I'd like to write my code to be independent of the actual database backend.  I know MySQL has a nice library, but I don't want to be tied to a single database implementation.  Are there good options for this?

Comment: Enterprise data access block is available in C#.  You could probably created some managed C++ wrappers if that's an option for you.

Answer (score 4):

[SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/) is good.  Supports multiple databases, works well, modern C++ style API, works with boost.

Answer (score 4):

My opinion is to forget about a cross-database driver, and focus on finding or creating a cross-database Data Access Layer.  A few reaons:

- Complex queries (read: anything that's not a toy) invariably end up using one or two database-specific features.  `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` for example, commonly used for paging, isn't universal.
- Sooner or later you'll want bulk insertion, and you'll want it to be as fast as possible, because 3 hours is better than 6 hours.  Every database has a different "optimum" way to do this, so your DAL will need to special-case this anyways.
- Different databases may expose different constraint mechanisms—even custom column types—that can be be worth taking advantage of where possible (PostgreSQL is wonderful for this).
- If you want to do any application level caching, you'll need a DAL *anyways*.

So, go ahead and use `libmysql` by itself - just hide it behind a compiler firewall in your DAL, and be prepared to swap it out later.  You can protect yourself from shifting infrastructure without having to use a lowest-common-denominator SQL wrapper.

If that doesn't jive with you, check out [SQLAPI++](http://www.sqlapi.com/).

Answer (score 1):

many apps use odbc (via [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org) for instance), there's also [otl](http://otl.sourceforge.net/otl3_whatn.htm). on windows you could use [ado.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ctka9db%28VS.80%29.aspx) from managed c++ or the old ado com interfaces...

Answer (score 1):

Qt provides a database abstraction layer. See: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qsqldatabase.html.

Answer (score 1):

[libodbc++](http://libodbcxx.sourceforge.net/) provides a pretty good API.
Also the big guys [Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qsqldatabase.html) (see Kyle Lutz' answer) & [wxWidgets](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.4/wx_odbcoverview.html) have db abstraction layers, so it may be a good idea to use them if you plan to use/you're already using any other parts of those frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenDBX](https://www.linuxnetworks.de/doc/index.php?title=OpenDBX) and [libzdb](http://www.tildeslash.com/libzdb/) are two lightweight candidates.  [Libgda](http://www.gnome-db.org/) for GNOME.

Comment: Wow 8 years later, I think this might be a personal best for me =D  Thank you!